# BitmapFactory.decodefile is returning null?

Tags: android, gridview, arraylist, bitmapfactory

I have made an ArrayList of 5 Bitmaps. For creating an ArrayList i have made my own class. Displayed the images in gridview. When i click at the grid view item, BitmapFactory.decodeFile() returns null because the position of item is not returned correctly. Here is code

Items.class

```
public class Items {
final String name;
public final int drawableId;

public Items(String name, int drawableId) {
    this.name = name;
    this.drawableId = drawableId;
  }
}
```

ArrayList and adding images in it

```
ArrayList<Items> bitmaps = new ArrayList<Items>();
bitmaps.add(new Items("image_name", R.drawable.image1));
```

At the time of showing image

```
ArrayList<Items> _bitmaps;
.....
String itemPosition = _bitmaps.get(position).toString();

Log.d("POS", "Item Position: " + itemPosition);

Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(itemPosition, options);
imgDisplay.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

Notice the Log.d. For the gridview's first item i.e. Position 0, it returns,

```
08-31 02:11:47.125: D/POS(943): Item Position: com.example.app.Items@405207f8
```

Comment: Have you tried cleaning your project?

Comment: can you post `getView` ?

Answer (score 0):

You are not getting Item position with this line,

```
String itemPosition = _bitmaps.get(position).toString();
```

You are casting the `Item` Class to string. You should do this to get the 'Name' of the object,

```
String itemPosition = _bitmaps.get(position).name;
```

Comment: and when i click on item 1 of grid view, the toast msg returns the name of item 1, item 2 and item 3 at the same time

Comment: Then the path is wrong. You should give path of the image to decode it as bitmap.